# try Google API Buckets: testIamPermissions for a specific service account

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I can use [Buckets: testIamPermissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/testIamPermissions) to test the permissions on a bucket for the logged in user.

Is there a way in which I can test it for a service account.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking another look on your question, I found a way to use [Buckets: testIamPermissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/testIamPermissions) with a Service Account:

You have to download the [service account’s key.json file](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) in your environment (with `gcloud` set up) and create an environment variable with:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[key.json]
```

Then, you can get a token of this service account via:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Finally, you can `curl` the `testIamPermissions` URL and pass that token as authorization header:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET]/iam/testPermissions?permissions=[PERMISSION]'   -H 'Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]’
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/getIamPolicy):

> To see if a service account has access to a resource, call the getIamPolicy method on the target resource. For example, to view grants for a project, call the projects.getIamPolicy method.

So to check if a Service Account has access to a Bucket, you have to use [Buckets: getIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/getIamPolicy) specifying the Bucket you want to check.

Comment: thanks for the reply. my actual concern is that if I use the link mentioned by u then I will access the resource using my gmail account and not the service account as I am logged into the browser using my email and I am not able to find a way to specify something that uses service account.

Comment: Service account aren't meant to be used in browsers. Can you specify a bit more your use case so we can help you better?

Comment: @LundinCast, I was trying my hands on cloud functions and wanted to build authentication into cloud function. for this i created a service account, created a storage bucket and gave SA read access on bucket. Ideally my authentication should have worked now but I was always getting permissions as null. So I wanted to test the permissions via API interface in a browser but I was not able to find a way.

Comment: Although I have fixed the issue in cloud function, it was that the promise function returned two objects 1) response 2) error and the positioning of error and response was swapped so i always received error in the object named response...